# Xamarin Forms List in Listview

Tags: list, listview, xamarin.forms

I need to display a request of an api inside a listview. Everything worked, but i have an attribute (notes) which returns a list and gives the following error message:

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Does anyone know a solution?

**TicketPage.xaml.cs**

```
public async void LoadTickets()
        {
            var content = "";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var RestURL = "https://...";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RestURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(RestURL);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Ticket item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticket>(content);
                List<Ticket> items = new List<Ticket> { item };
                ListViewTicket.ItemsSource = items;
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Testtext","Ok");
            }
        }
```

**TicketPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <ListView x:Name="ListViewTicket" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="None" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Im nachfolgenden sehen Sie Ihre offenen Tickets" FontSize="Medium"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ListView.Header>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="5" Color="Blue" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket ID:"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding id}" Padding="-60,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket Status:"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding status}" Padding="-60,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket Betreff:"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding subject}" Padding="-60,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket Nachricht:"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding message}" Padding="-60,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket Notiz:"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding notes}" Padding="-60,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="5" Color="Blue" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: You are bing a list of some type to a property which is Text that is expecting one string element only

Comment: You can display a nested LIstView (usually a bad idea).  You can use a Grouped ListView.  You can have a 2nd page or popup that displays the list of associated notes.  You can build a custom cell that displays some subset of the Notes.  There are a lot of ways to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BindableLayout` to display a collection of items without wrapping it in another `ListView`. It can be done like this:

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                            <Grid>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket ID:"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding id}"/>
                            </Grid>

                            <!-- I've removed some code for brevity -->

                            <Grid>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket Notiz:"/>
                                <!-- HERE! display collection of notes, each note in it's own Label -->
                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding notes}">
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Thank you Michal that is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Pentium Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Since the attribute (`notes`) returns a list , you can't simply bind it to a `Label`.In this condition, it will show :

`System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`

```
  <Grid>
       <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket Notiz:"/>
       <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding notes}" Padding="-60,0,0,0"/>
  </Grid>
```

> Does anyone know a solution?

For this, you can use a Grouping listview to achieve this. For more check: [grouping ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping).

You can also define two pages,once we click the out listview, we can navigate to the second page or just pop up the list of associated notes,just as Jason mendtioned.